# is it possible to pass Linq.Queryable.Max as a parameter?

Tags: c#

I have the following method

```
private double Test(IQueryable<MyClass> items, Func<IQueryable<MyClass>, double> func)
{
    var specificItems = GetSpecificItems(items);

    var value = func(specificItems);

    return value;
}
```

Where I would like to pass to `func` the `System.Linq.Queryable.Max` method, to determine the max value of some class property of `MyClass`

I tried calling it like this

```
var test = Test(items, System.Linq.Queryable.Max<double>);
```

With the idea to pass a 3rd parametesr `selector` to tell which property `Max` should select

However, I get stuck at the above with this error

> Argument 2: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'Func<IQueryable, double>'

Is what I am trying to achieve even possible?

Ultimately I would like my method call to look something like this

```
var test = Test(items, System.Linq.Queryable.Max<double>, x => x.PropertyToGetMaxOf);
```

Comment: would `Test(items, x => x.Max())` do? You'd need to change the signature of your method to take `Func<IQueryable<double>, double>` though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do is:

```
var test = Test(items, x => x.Max(c => c.PropertyToGetMaxOf));
```